# how to check some assembly is present in client and register that if not

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, assemblies, gac

what i want to know is that how can i use assembly that is register in GAC in my C# application.
Detail: What i want to achieved is that

1) Check ABC assembly that is register in my client machine or not from my windows
   application

2) If not then register that assemble in `GAC` of client from my windows application

3) And use this assembly and perform some functions

Remember that that ABC assemble is my assembly having some of my function.

Comment: What setup program are you using?

Comment: am not using any set up program, just checking it in in windows application.

Comment: You should be using a setup program. I can't imagine why an application would need to modify the GAC during regular operation. More importantly, trying to do this will get you into serious problems with that other acronym—UAC. If you just need to load an assembly to perform some functions, you should ***not*** be registering it in the GAC. You probably shouldn't be using the GAC anyway, unless you have a specific need to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Use the IAssemblyCache interface via COM Interop. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/junfeng/archive/2004/09/14/229649.aspx